# Gphoto2 Capture Video and Download

Tags: video, command-line-interface, libgphoto2

I have used gphoto in the past to capture images and download them directly to my computer instead of using the sd card in the camera. I am wondering if it is possible to do this for videos as well or to copy the file video file to the computer upon successful recording. I am looking for the video/movie equivalent to `--capture-image-and-download` or another program that can accomplish this with a DSLR from the command line

Answer (score 3):

Depend of your DSLR but is possible, see the commande line here ("Movie Capture"): http://gphoto.org/doc/remote/

Edit :

> Capturing movies with sound is currently possible with:
>
> Newer Nikon DSLRs: gphoto2 --set-config movie=1 --wait-event=10s
>   --set-config movie=0 --wait-event-and-download=2s. Replace 10s by the number of seconds you want to have your movie long. This started being
>   supported around 2012, around the D7000 release.
>
> Newer Canon EOS DSLRs (around 7D and later) : Switch the camera to
>   movie record mode on the camera. Then run gphoto2 --set-config
>   viewfinder=1 --set-config movierecordtarget=Card --wait-event=10s
>   --set-config movierecordtarget=None --wait-event-and-download=2s (before 2.5.6, replace viewfinder by eosviewfinder). If this does not
>   work, check and switch the capturetarget to SD Card (gphoto2
>   --set-config capturetarget=1)
>
> Older cameras with preview capture ability: gphoto2
>   --capture-movie=10s . This will capture 10 seconds of preview frames and concatenate them in a MotionJPEG style stream.

For Canon you need to change --set-config movierecordtarget=Card to --set-config movierecordtarget=0 and --set-config movierecordtarget=None to --set-config movierecordtarget=1.